# SQLiteDatabase error “sqlite: (1) near "(": syntax error

Tags: android, sqlite

Help me please,I am don't understand it .i will be create data base but it error.please i will be end example project next night .please help me

code

```
public class FriendsDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static int TABLE_VERSION = 1;
    public static String TABLE_NAME ="table_f";
    public static String TABLE_KEY_ID = "id";
    public static String TABLE_KEY_FNAME = "fname";
    public static String TABLE_KEY_LNAME = "lname";
    public static String TABLE_KEY_NNAME = "nickname";

    public static String TABLE_CREATE_SQL = "CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME+" ("+
                                            ""+TABLE_KEY_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+
                                            ""+TABLE_KEY_FNAME+"TEXT(20), "+
                                            ""+TABLE_KEY_LNAME+"TEXT(20), "+
                                            ""+TABLE_KEY_NNAME+"TEXT(20), "+
                                            ") ";
    //Constructor
    public FriendsDBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, TABLE_NAME, null, TABLE_VERSION);

    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        db.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE_SQL);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE "+TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
        Log.i("Friends DB Helper","Table upgrade form "+ oldVersion +" to "+newVersion);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need whitespace between column names and types here:

```
""+TABLE_KEY_FNAME+"TEXT(20), "+
""+TABLE_KEY_LNAME+"TEXT(20), "+
""+TABLE_KEY_NNAME+"TEXT(20), "+
```

To fix another syntax error, remove the `,` after the last column spec.

Better:

```
""+TABLE_KEY_FNAME+" TEXT(20), "+
""+TABLE_KEY_LNAME+" TEXT(20), "+
""+TABLE_KEY_NNAME+" TEXT(20) "+
```

The parens are syntactically valid (but semantically ignored) for column type but not for column name.

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra "," at the end of create table command.

```
""+TABLE_KEY_NNAME+"TEXT(20), "+
```

Remove that.

Also `""+TABLE_KEY_FNAME+"TEXT(20), "+` it will evaluate as `""+TABLE_KEY_FNAMETEXT(20), "+` i.e. without space between field and type, so add a space like:

```
""+TABLE_KEY_FNAME+" TEXT(20), "+
```

Similar changes applies to other field definition as well.